# Как убрать расширение .html в конце URL сайта?

Tags: html

Я использую handyhost, может быть кто-то знает как у этого хостинга убрать расширение .html в конце URL?

Comment: Дополните вопрос: какую CMS Вы используете (если пользуетесь), какой веб-сервер установлен (Apache, Nginx)? Название хостинга ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/78158